# iOS send data using socket connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sockets, tcp

I have implemented socket connection in iOS.

What I want to do is to send string of data to the connected device...
(I am able to receive data when someone sends to my device)
I have tried this code but data is getting received on other device, when I close my app.

```
- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Setting up connection to %@ : %i", _ipAddressText.text, [_portText.text intValue]);
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) _ipAddressText.text, [_portText.text intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);

    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self open];
}

- (void)open {

    NSLog(@"Opening streams.");

    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];

    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [outputStream open];
    [inputStream open];

    _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %lu", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            _connectedLabel.text = @"Connected";
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == inputStream)
            {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                NSInteger len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            NSLog(@"Stream has space available now");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"error: %@",[theStream streamError].localizedDescription);
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            _connectedLabel.text = @"Disconnected";
            NSLog(@"close stream");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}

 /* Sends data to other device */
 - (IBAction) sendMessage {

    NSLog(@"sendMessage");
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"msg:%@", _dataToSendText.text];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"[data length] %lu",(unsigned long)[data length]);
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

 }
```

Where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing hard research i found adding `\n` at the end of string message indicates my buffer has received whole string.
now start sending a file, so it worked...

To send a String over Sockets, you must mark the end of the string. ie; Add a `\n`

Answer (score 0):

To mark a string with start and end of string there are `ASCII control characters` to do so, the octets are `\002` & `\003` respectively. I would recommend using these control characters instead of just adding a line break, your text could have line breaks and that could create problems.